# Java Socket closing OutputStream

Tags: java, sockets, java-7

I have always learned to *always* close a stream when I finish using it. Java 7 gives you a new option to do this (namely: try-with-resources), and it's all fine, except that when I close the `OutputStream` of a socket, the socket gets closed aswell. This is counter-productive, because I am using sockets in a streaming application.

So if I execute the code below, I understand the `ObjectOutputStream` gets closed after the try-block, and the socket's `OutputStream` gets closed too, which *finally* leads to closing my Socket.

```
try(ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())) {
   oos.writeObject(new MyDTO(data));
}
```

I could of course change my code to look like below, but everyone has always told me I should close my Streams when I finish using them. And this is just *one* method, but I have multiple other methods which also use the `OutputStream` and `ObjectOutputStream` to send data to my client(s).

```
try {
   ObjectOutputStream oos = new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream())
   oos.writeObject(new MyDTO(data));
}
```

Do I have to expect other errors and misbehaviors as a result of not closing the `ObjectOutputStream`? I think it's nice that the socket is closed, when you have bursty-traffic applications, but it is kind-of weird when you're doing a streaming application.

What's the best practice? Teach me please.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously if you still need the resources, you won't close them. The idea is to close them **after** you're done with them. If you're creating a chat software, you'd keep the connection open and the resources in use. However if you were to create some sort of poor man's FTP software, you might want to close the connection after the file has been transferred.

The `try-with-resources` is to make it easier to write code that is guaranteed to release its resources, which is often useful when dealing with streams, database connections and other such things. You don't *have* to use it everywhere, especially when it makes your work harder.

Comment: Thanks for your input. My question was more about if there could be any problems if I reuse the OutputStream and use it with more than one ObjectOutputStream. The ObjectOutputStreams get finalized correctly/don't have influence on the Socket, after I exit their scope (i.e. the try-block)?

Comment: Even if it did work, it's not smart to close a stream that you're not done using yet. It's just unnecessary work on your part.

Answer (score 1):

The question doesn't really make sense. You can't in practice create multiple `ObjectOutputStreams` over the same socket (and even if you know how to do it there is no advantage), so there is no reason to be using try-with-resources with the `ObjectOutputStream` in the first place. It should be created along with the socket, almost certainly stored as an instance member somewhere, and closed when you're finished with the connection.

Comment: As I said, I always learned to close my streams. So you would recommend that I create an OutputStream together with my socket and have it as instance in my controller? Because right now I create an Output/Input stream every time my method(s) are called.

Comment: Then you learned by rote instead of applying intelligence. If you had applied the pattern I described here of using an instance member for the streams, you wouldn't - *couldn't* - have fallen into this trap. I don't see any need to repeat my answer *verbatim*, which is all you appear to be asking for.

Comment: Yes, but if I have a Server with a lot of connections, all stored in a collection. I would have to map an other collection of the ObjectOutputStream? This is why I never evaluated the possibility to have instantiated ObjectOutputStreams, and went for the just-in-time instantiation as a local variable, when the method gets called.

Comment: Of course I could wrap everything up in a class, but I tought it would be easier.

Comment: It isn't easier when it doesn't work. You will have to find a way to use the same streams for the life of the socket.